# Parse invalid session token error 1.8.2

Tags: ios, swift, session, parse-platform

I am currently getting this error in the terminal of my application when I run it. It was working fine not to long ago but now I am getting an Invalid Session Token error and I'm not sure why. I have tried to resolve this issue with no success.

I have tried reading upon this parse help tutorial on how to fix this error with the link https://www.parse.com/tutorials/session-migration-tutorial, but when I try entering that line of iOS code in the line below where I enter the client & Application ID, it does not run (I get a failed error).

I have also have "Require Revocable Sessions" enabled in the dashboard of ma application which it says to do in the link provided.

If anybody else is having this issue and can help me solve it, that would be fantastic, thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly stated on the dashboard and in the documentation. If you enable "Require Revocable Sessions", all sessions that use legacy tokens (non revocable) will be invalidated and you will have to login again.

You have 2 possibilities :

- Your app is in production and you have users using it with an old version of the SDK (meaning they use old tokens). Then you should disable "Require Revocable Sessions" immediately.
- You're still developing your app, then leave "Require Revocable Sessions" enabled, do not add the migration code and just re install your app.