# Parse login issue invalid login parameters

Tags: ios, parse-platform

when i try to login to Parse on ios simulator using my app id and client id it shows "invalid login parameters (Code: 101, Version: 1.8.2)" but when i tried Udemy's ios tutor's app id and client id it was  worked. My code is alright and i think the problem is in Parse. Is there anybody has had an issue like this?

import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var signUp = true // for creating current mode of the page

@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
```

// login iv outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var signUpB: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var loginB: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var registerText: UILabel!
var activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView() // for spinner

//for displaying alert 
func displayAlert(title:String,message:String){

    var alert = UIAlertController(title:title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .Default , handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    })))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

@IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {

    if username.text == "" || password.text == "" {

    displayAlert("Error in form", message: "Please enter username and password")



    }

    else  {

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center

        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        var errorMessage = "Please try again later"
        if signUp == true
        {

        var user = PFUser()
        user.username = username.text
        user.password = username.text


        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock(

            {(success, error) -> Void in

            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if error == nil
            {
            // sign up successful
            }
            else  {
                if let errorString = error!.userInfo?["error"] as? String
                {

                    errorMessage = errorString
                }
                self.displayAlert("Failed ", message: errorMessage)

                   }

              })
          }      else  {


                       PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text, password: password.text, block:
                        { (user, error) -> Void in

                            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                            if user != nil
                                  {
                                     //  logged in
                                   }

                            else   {


                                if let errorString = error!.userInfo?["error"] as? String
                                {

                                    errorMessage = errorString
                                }
                                self.displayAlert("Failed Login", message: errorMessage)


                                    }

                         })
                        }



            }



       }

@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {
    if signUp == true {

        signUpB.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        registerText.text = "Not Registered?"
        loginB.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        signUp = false
    }

    else{

        signUpB.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        registerText.text = "Already Registered?"
        loginB.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        signUp = true

    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.














}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Show your code. Also make sure you installed the parse frameworks and went through their mini tutorial they give you after you create a new app on parse.com. At the end of the tutorial, it will let you test your set up and notify you if you've set it up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error "invalid login parameter" and I know why.

The problem is the response message itself from Parse, it makes us confused.

"Invalid login parameter" means "Wrong username or password".

Just enter the right username and password and it's done!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem, two things I did:

1. in AppDelegate I commented out

//        PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground()

more here: [Parse invalid session token error 1.8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383929/parse-invalid-session-token-error-1-8-2)

2 In your login viewController (after updating to new Facebook SDK) I added the following:

import ParseFacebookUtilsV4