# Parse and Swift - PFGeoPoint with CLLocationManager?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm fairly new to the understanding of using CoreLocation and Parse so please bear with me! I code with swift and a lot of SO posts I've been searching have been in Obc-C which i am very unfamiliar with.

**.................................................................UPDATE.......................................................................**
Trying to store current users location into the Parse database but its not working. I get the error:

[Error]: invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.9.1)
Optional(Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)")"

Any suggestions / help to point me in the right direction?

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var manager: CLLocationManager!
var activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

@IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {

    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    let user = PFUser()
    user.username = username.text
    user.password = password.text

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        if error == nil {

            PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    print("got location successfully")
                    PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(geoPoint, forKey:"location")
                    PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()

                } else {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)

        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {

    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text!, password: password.text!) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend storing the geopoint within your `User` class. Also, rather than adding a geopoint to each `Post`, you should add a ***pointer*** to the `User` who created it. This eliminates the redundancy of storing the location twice and makes sure you don't have to mess with keeping the two variables in sync. Additionally, this is also much better practice than storing the objectId directly.

Update your `Post` class to have a `User` pointer column called `user`. Then instead of

```
postEvent["userId"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!
```

Use

```
postEvent["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()!
```

It's also worth pointing out that Parse includes [helper methods to get the current user's locations](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#geopoints-getting-the-user-39-s-current-location). It's as simple as the following

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
    (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // do something with the new geoPoint
    }
}
```

If you do decide to handle the `CLLocationManager` yourself, make sure to call `stopUpdatingLocation()` to save battery life once you've updated the user's location, assuming you don't need continuous location updates.

From there, you can use [query constraints](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-query-constraints) and a [compound query](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-compound-queries) to get all of the nearby `Post` objects. In particular, you will want to use `whereKey: matchesQuery:` as the compound query which only counts as 1 API request.

```
// User's location
let userGeoPoint = userObject["location"] as PFGeoPoint

// Query nearby Users
let nearbyUserQuery : PFQuery = PFUser.query()
nearbyUserQuery.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint)

// Query Posts constrained to nearby Users
let nearbyPostQuery : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

// Use a compound query to constrain the results to nearby Users
nearbyPostQuery.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: nearbyUserQuery)

// Limit the number of Posts if needed
nearbyPostQuery.limit = 20

nearbyPostQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (posts: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // Do something with the Posts
}
```

Comment: Russell, thanks so much for your response. I have a question for you and would love to have your feedback. You mention that I should store the users location in the User class...in my app, I created my user class during the "sign up" phase. Would you advise against storing the users location on sign up? Or would it make more sense to UPDATE the users location when the user is viewing the "Feed" and/or posting an image?

Comment: Happy to help! I would recommend storing/updating the user's location each time the app is opened. You can do all of it in the background so it never interferes with the UI or is restricted to particular views.

Comment: Russell - I've created a new "dummy" app to practice the steps you've suggested but i'm getting caught up in this helper method and storing the users location with the PFUser object. Do you mind taking a look at my updated question and corresponding code? Once again, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Nope you shouldn't need the commented out area unless you are trying to use reverse geocoding. Reverse geocoding is the process of converting a latitude/longitude pair into an address, city, zip code, etc. So if you are wanting that functionality, then yes you will still need to use that.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting errors and the locations are not storing in Parse. I've updated my post to show this...do you mind looking at my code to see where I could be going wrong?

Comment: The location code looks solid to me. It seems like this error is unrelated to fetching the locations, but rather is related to the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383929/parse-invalid-session-token-error-1-8-2

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that part of SO guidelines is to post a new question when encountering a different problem from what the original post was about. Part of my answer could now be confusing since it is no longer mentioned in the OP. Try to stay away from updating the original question too much :)

Comment: Wow, thanks so much Russell ! I can't believe it was something as simple as having to delete my app from the simulator and then re-running it in order to store my geopoint in the parse backend...And i apologize for re-creating my original question! I wasn't sure how SO works in terms of asking questions. I will keep this is mind for the future! Thanks again Russell I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Not a problem at all and happy to help!